# CSOM - Check if one root site collection

Tags: site-collection, csom

I have a situation in which I'd like to know whether the user is currently on their root site collection or not.

I tried the following:

```
var siteRelativeUrl = ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
var isRoot = siteRelativeUrl.Equals("/");
```

But apparently this fails some times, so I guess you can have a none root site collection consisting of `https://test.sharepoint.com/`.

I was wondering and hoping that CSOM had some way of checking this, or if any had some suggestions as of what to do?

Comment: use SP.Site.get_rootWeb() in some variable & compare it with your existing

Answer (score 3):

You could compare the ID with the RootWeb:

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site.RootWeb, rw => rw.Id);
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.Id);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var isRoot = (clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Id == clientContext.Web.Id) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Question is about root site collection, not root site.

Comment: @dstarkowski you are right, don't know why I didn't see that :)